# Можно ли в .htaccess иметь все эти настройки одновременно

Tags: .htaccess

Из всего понемножку понабирал и вышел такой `.htaccess`. и хотя саит и работает нормально, но думаю, что что-то тут не так. Если кто найдет, что не так, пожалуйста, объясните как можно детально (что и почему).

С остальными настройками понятно, вот часть где непонятно:

```
<files .htaccess>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</files>
<files readme.html>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</files>
<files readme.txt>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</files>
<files install.php>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</files>
<files wp-config.php>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</files>

# Rules to disable XML-RPC
<files xmlrpc.php>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</files>
<Files "wp-login.php">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from (moi ip adres )
</Files>

Options All -Indexes

# Rules to disable directory browsing
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Rules to protect wp-includes
    RewriteRule ^wp-admin/includes/ - [F]
    RewriteRule !^wp-includes/ - [S=3]
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !^(.*)wp-includes/ms-files.php
    RewriteRule ^wp-includes/[^/]+\.php$ - [F]
    RewriteRule ^wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/.+\.php - [F]
    RewriteRule ^wp-includes/theme-compat/ - [F]

    # Rules to prevent php execution in uploads
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/uploads/(.*).php(.?) - [F]

    # Rules to block unneeded HTTP methods
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|DELETE|TRACK) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]

    # Rules to block suspicious URIs
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \.\.\/ [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*\.(bash|git|hg|log|svn|swp|cvs) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} etc/passwd [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} boot\.ini [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ftp\:  [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} http\:  [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} https\:  [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|%3D) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(%24&x).* [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(127\.0).* [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(globals|encode|localhost|loopback).* [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(request|concat|insert|union|declare).* [NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^loggedout=true
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^action=jetpack-sso
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^action=rp
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in_.*$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://maps\.googleapis\.com(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    AddEncoding gzip .gz
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} !gzip [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Safari [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Konqueror
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.gz(\?.+)?$ $1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php52 .php .php5 .php4 .php3

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(html|htm)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=43200"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|txt)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
    </FilesMatch>
   <FilesMatch "\.(flv|swf|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.(pl|php|cgi|spl|scgi|fcgi)$">
        Header unset Cache-Control
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access 30 days"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 30 day"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 year"
</IfModule>
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
<filesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\.(css|js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\.(xml|txt)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=172800, public, must-revalidate"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\.(html|htm|php)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=172800, private, must-revalidate"
</filesMatch>
</ifModule>
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
BrowserMatch "MSIE" force-no-vary
BrowserMatch "Mozilla/4.[0-9]{2}" force-no-vary
</IfModule>
</ifModule>
FileETag MTime Size
<ifmodule mod_expires.c>
<filesmatch "\.(jpg|gif|png|css|js)$">
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault "access 30 days"
</filesmatch>
</ifmodule>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/javascript text/css application/x-javascript
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript
</ifModule>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .wp-comments-post\.php*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !.*(moi sait).* [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) ^http://%{REMOTE_ADDR}/$ [R=301,L]
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Vary User-Agent
    <FilesMatch .*\.js.gz$>
    ForceType text/javascript
    Header set Content-Encoding: gzip
    Header set Cache-control: private
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch .*\.css.gz$>
    ForceType text/css
    Header set Content-Encoding: gzip
    Header set Cache-control: private
    </FilesMatch>
<ifModule mod_php.c>
  php_value upload_max_filesize 32M
  php_value post_max_size       10M
  php_value default_charset utf-8
  php_value max_execution_time 200
</ifModule>
<IfModule mod_gzip.c>
    mod_gzip_on         Yes
    mod_gzip_dechunk    Yes
    mod_gzip_item_include file      \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime      ^text\.*
    mod_gzip_item_include mime      ^application/x-javascript.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude mime      ^image\.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</IfModule>
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    #кэшировать html и htm файлы на один день
    <FilesMatch "\.(html|htm)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=43200"
    </FilesMatch>
    #кэшировать css, javascript и текстовые файлы на одну неделю
    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|txt)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
    </FilesMatch>
    #кэшировать флэш и изображения на месяц
    <FilesMatch "\.(flv|swf|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
    </FilesMatch>
    #отключить кэширование
    <FilesMatch "\.(pl|php|cgi|spl|scgi|fcgi)$">
        Header unset Cache-Control
    </FilesMatch>
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    #по умолчанию кеш в 5 секунд
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 seconds"
    #кэшировать флэш и изображения на месяц
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    #кэшировать css, javascript и текстовые файлы на одну неделю
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
    #кэшировать html и htm файлы на один день
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 43200 seconds"
    #кэшировать xml файлы на десять минут
    ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
</ifModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: То есть вы "понабрали отовсюду понемногу", не понимая, зачем это Вам? Плохой подход. Вебмастера с таким подходом чаще всех притаскивают на свои сайты бекдоры и прочую вирусню, "набирая отовсюду понемногу". Код должен решать конкретную, понятную Вам задачу. Иначе этот код не нужен и вреден.

Answer (score 3):

Всё очень просто. Кликаем в [документацию](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html), ищем там директиву, в которой сомневаемся, и проверяем: разрешено её использовать в `.htaccess` или нет. Заодно и детали всякие узнаем быстрей, чем вслепую тыкаться или на форумах ждать ответов :)

Например, хотим узнать про `<Files>`. Кликаем в [Configuration Sections](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html), там в [`<Files>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#files). Читаем, проникаемся (не забываем кликать по поясняющим ссылкам в разделе, и вообще, крутить головой в разные стороны), заодно видим радующую нас строку:

> Context:  server config, virtual host, directory, .htaccess

P.S. Впрочем, если на самом деле что-то не так, то правильный апач выдаст 500 и сообщит об ошибке в своих логах.

Comment: спасибо вам большое за помощь